# How do I access Paint.Picture OLE Class External Properties and Functions in PowerBuilder

Tags: powerbuilder, ole

I have jpeg image files of A4 Size displayed on a window in PowerBuilder 12.5 using PB Image Controls (PictureButton, Picture, InkPicture) vs OLE Control (Paintbrush Picture). When compared the OLE option displayed clearer than the Picture Controls.

I'll like to use the OLE option (due to its clearity) but will like to determine the image file using my code. But I do not know how access the OLE Object External Functions and Properties in my code as these are not available in the PowerBuilder Object Browser.

Is there a way to get the list of the Paint.Picture OLE Class's Functions/Properties or make any of the PB Picture Controls display clearer without increasing the control's size?

Thanks

[image: Image in PB Picture Conrol vs OLE Control]

Answer (score 1):

**Examining OLE Class Functions and/or Properties in PowerBuilder**

1. From the **Tools** menu in PowerBuilder choose "**Browser**..." menu item.
2. Choose the **OLE Tab**
3. Double click an appropriate **OLE category** such as "**OLE Custom Controls**".
4. Choose a registered **OLE control** and expand the tree view
5. View the **Class Information**, **Properties** and/or **Functions**

You mentioned this not showing in the Object Browser. I'm not sure why it wouldn't show up if registered. You could refer to the Microsoft Paintbrush API documentation as a fail safe.

Answer (score 0):

You can use progid value in class information to acces object